# How to do prediction when use tensorflow nce_loss for training

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, loss-function

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/nce_loss
Here it says `calculate the full sigmoid loss for evaluation or inference`, can anyone explain some detail how to predict the label in the inference period?

As I understand the model's last layer output is of shape (batch, num_class), during training it directly goes into nce loss and is treated as a binary classification problem. During inference, is it right that I directly take the sigmoid over the last layer output and get the corresponding entry `i` to represent the probability of class `i`? Or I can directly treat the largest entry as the class label just like using softmax?

Not quite understand this, neither have I found any practical example related to this online. Any help is appreciated! Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when you consider the sequence input, NCE_loss is the noise-contrastive estimation that varies input to create the output by selecting acandidate sampler.

Ref 0: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/nce_loss

Ref 1: https://github.com/yl-1993/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py

Ref 2:  https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/90447/tensorflow.nce_loss

**[ Sample ]:**

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)   

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
learning_rate = 0.001
global_step = 0
vocabulary_size = 5000
start = 0
limit = 128
delta = 1
embedding_size = 16
n_sample = 16

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

# Input data.

inputs = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('X', dtype = tf.int32, initializer = tf.random.uniform(shape=[1], maxval=1, dtype=tf.int32, seed=10))
labels = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('Y', dtype = tf.int32, initializer = tf.random.uniform(shape=[1, 1], maxval=1, dtype=tf.int32, seed=10))

# Look up embeddings for inputs.
embeddings = tf.Variable(
tf.random.uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0)
)
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, inputs)

# Construct the variables for the NCE loss
nce_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.random.uniform(shape=[vocabulary_size, embedding_size], maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32,)
)
nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

# Compute the average NCE loss for the batch.
# tf.nce_loss automatically draws a new sample of the negative labels each
# time we evaluate the loss.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(
tf.nn.nce_loss(nce_weights, nce_biases,
               labels=labels,
               inputs=embed,
               num_sampled=n_sample,
               num_classes=vocabulary_size),
name='loss'
)
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
    learning_rate,
    initial_accumulator_value=0.1,
    l1_regularization_strength=0.2,
    l2_regularization_strength=0.1,
    use_locking=False,
    name='ProximalAdagrad'
)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='minimize') 


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSet / Input
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
X = np.reshape([ 500 ], (1))
Y = np.reshape([ 15 ], (1, 1))
history = [ ] 

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training / Optimize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    
    for i in range(1000):
        global_step = global_step + 1
        train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={inputs:X, labels:Y})
        history.append(train_loss)
        
        print( 'steps: ' + str(i) )
        
sess.close()

print( history )
plt.plot(history)
plt.show()
plt.close()

input('...')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my main question is how to do prediction after training with nce loss, seems the references and the code you provide doesn't explicitly answer this... Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: My example simply a code how you apply the "tf.nn.nce_loss" per your question with labels input.

Comment: My question is not apply loss but how to predict after training with this loss......